# case-sensitive INSERT IGNORE on a latin1 character set MySQL table

Tags: mysql

```
$ CREATE TABLE `test` ( `data` char(64), UNIQUE KEY `key` (`data`));
$ INSERT IGNORE INTO test (data) VALUES ('a');
$ INSERT IGNORE INTO test (data) VALUES ('A');
$ SELECT * FROM test;
+------+
| data |
+------+
| a    |
+------+
```

How can I get the second `INSERT IGNORE` to add a new entry into the table? Is it possible without redefining the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is refusing to insert the duplicate row as it should.  If you want the `data` column to be case insensitive you will have to alter the table:

```
ALTER TABLE `test` CHANGE `data` `data` CHAR( 64 )
CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible without DDL. You'd need to change the column collation:

```
alter table test modify data char(64) collate utf8_bin;
```